# Reading ApplicationData in Powershell

Tags: 2013, powershell

I've been playing with a script to get the Application Data on all publications - at the moment I just want to write it out to see what's in there.

I've confirmed several publications have tm: (Translation Manager) App Data but only get null of the Application Data below:

```
$pubsList = Get-TridionPublications | Select-Object Title, Id, ExtensionData;
$pubsTotal = "Total of " + $myPubs.Count + " Publications";
Write-Output $pubsTotal;
for ($i=0; $i -lt $pubsList.length; $i++) {
    [string]$title = $pubsList[$i].Title;

    if($title.StartsWith("030")){

        $pub = $pubsList[$i];

        $pub.Title;

        $appData = $core.ReadAllApplicationData($pub.Id);

        if ($appData -ne $null) {

            $appData

        }
        else {
            Write-Output "No AppData";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the appdata companion? http://sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/appdata.aspx or are you just honing your PowerShell skillz?

Comment: I had seen this Nuno - my client is very specific about putting the minimum into their environment and I need to walk them through each line. So it's a chance to beef up on the beast that is PowerShell and ensure I can articulate every step of the way to the client :)

Comment: https://github.com/TridionPractice/tridion-practice/wiki/WorkingWithAppData

Comment: Just a note that I've been adding support for Application Data on a feature brand of the Tridion PowerShell Modules. Feel free to have a look at that one (it will get merged to 'master' sometime soon): https://github.com/pkjaer/tridion-powershell-modules/tree/alchemy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On closer investigation of the Publication Object - this exposes the App Data as the ExtensionData as follows:

$pubsList = Get-TridionPublications | Select-Object Title, Id, ExtensionData;

This gives me the Application Data as System Object.

Comment: Really?!  ExtensionData is a special WCF property used to store unrecognized data in (for forward compatibility purposes). The Core Service doesn't return Application Data together with the rest of the object's state, so if your claim is true, somebody must have done a really "creative" implementation of `Get-TridionPublications`!

Comment: You're correct Rick - I was a bit quick off the mark there... I have access to what I need through the ReadAllApplicationData method and the ExtensionData isn't  the app data 'object' and can be removed from the example above (I'd played with this a little and had tried to access via ExensionData) - I'll spend a little more time cleaning up the code (probably ending up with something more attuned to the appdata companion if time permits

Answer (score 3):

I have a function that does it this way:

```
#Example call:     $appData2 = Get-TridionApplicationData -ObjectId $pubId -ApplicationId "tm:ItemTranslationOptions" -Verbose
```

here's the guts of the function code

```
$client = Get-TridionCoreServiceClient
$ad = $client.ReadApplicationData($ObjectId, $ApplicationId)
if ($ad -ne $null)
{
$data = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($ad.Data)
return $data
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I've done in the modules (on a feature branch at the moment). Some of the app data is using a different encoding, though. I apologize in advance for the future naming conflict :)